# Xcode 6.1.1 Instruments Can Not Use Counters Template on Devices

Tags: xcode6, xcode-instruments

XCode 6.1.1 Instruments 6.1

Can use the Counters template fine on Simulator, but not on devices.  Get the warning / error message:

```
"The current OS does not have support for your CPU"
```

The Red Button is greyed out and can not start the session.

Can only run Counters on the Simulator?

This is from an XCode PRODUCT / PROFILE with target as a device and not a simulator.

iPhone 4 and iPad Mini both exhibit this problem.

Comment: Is there a yellow warning icon for the Counters instrument in the trace document window? If so, that means the instrument is not compatible with the device. My guess is the Counters instrument works only with Intel CPUs, but I don't have an iOS device compatible with Xcode 6.1 to test my guess.

Comment: @ort11 Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Same thing with Xcode 7.2.1. I can't get Counters to work with my iPhone 5. I get the same message. If I switch to the simulator I get a similar message.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Xcode, currently 7.2.1 as of this writing, apparently only supports 64-bit processors when using Counters. For 64-bit, you'll need an [Apple A7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_A7) or newer so the following are currently the minimum supported devices:

- iPhone 5s
- iPad Air
- iPad Mini 2